# "button" com conteudo invisível

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, button, contents

Existe como setar um conteúdo para um `button` em WPF, mas que ele esteja invisível ao usuário?

Comment: Qual sua intenção? Talvez não precise fazer isto. E se precisar, dependendo da intenção tem uma forma diferente.

Comment: Estou tentando fazer uma batalha naval usando os botões e meu pouco conhecimento kkkk.

Comment: @Ayo você poderia usar um vetor (array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não precisa fazer isto. Botão é botão, dados são dados, eles precisa estar separados. Nem sei se deveria usar um botão, mas acho que o máximo que deveria ter dentro dele é uma figura, um texto que indique o que tem ali, mas isto não deveria ser usado como dado.

Você pode fazer isto:

```
<Button>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock>Texto se achar que deve ter algum</TextBlock>
        <Image Source="submarino.png" />
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Há casos que pode ser útil assim:

```
<Button>
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
       <Image Source="destroierParte1.png" />
       <Label>Texto aqui</Label>
   </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/WPF/Button.xaml).

No WPF dá para compor de várias formas, tem que usar a criatividade.

Obviamente que provavelmente vai começar o `source` com uma imagem escondendo o objeto a ser mostrado. Quando ele for clicado a imagem deverá ser mudada, talvez invocando alguns efeitos. Na mudança, você mudará o vetor de dados que controlará quais partes já foram vistas e vai disparar um evento quando todo navio for mostrado, atualizará placar, etc.

Enfim, só dando algumas dicas, parece simples, mas tem várias coisas que precisam acontecer em uma batalha naval.

Comment: entendi ... obrigado pela ajuda. Você acha melhor usar botoes ? de que outra forma você faria?